# How to get sets of Records in VB6?

Tags: vb6

Hey guys, just want to ask you a simple question that I know you're familiar with... I am using VB6, I just want to get sets of records from my database. What I mean is that I have UserID and with a part of code provided below, it only gets a *single set of record*. Like for instance, the value of UserID is **`A12`**, and so, all sets of records with the UserID of **`A12`** must display in Textboxes respectively with the aid of **`datPayroll.Recordset.MoveNext`**.

```
With datPayroll
    .RecordSource = "select * from tblpayroll where empid like '" & UserID & "'"
    .Refresh
    Me.txtRegularHours.Text = .Recordset.Fields!reghours
End With
```

-datPayroll : DataControl

-txtRegularHours : Textbox

-UserID : Variable

Comment: It returns all that matched, though you don't seem to be providing any pattern symbols so why not "=" instead of "LIKE" here?  Not sure how you want it to work anyway.  Bumping the cursor forward or back is not unlike incrmenting/decrementing a subscript.

Comment: Also I'm not sure why you use a DataControl but fail to bind your TextBoxes.  I won't mention your vulnerability to SQL injection attacks, somebody else probably will.

Comment: @Bob Riemersma, what would be the syntax? `"select * from tblpayroll where empid = '" & UserID & "'"` is this right?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look at MoveFirst, MoveNext, etc. and also EOF

Here is a link or two to get you started:

[EOF, BOF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675787%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[MoveFirst, MoveNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677527%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You need to check that you have some data in your Recordset using EOF, then MoveFirst to move to the first record, and loop through using MoveNext.